# Internet Explorer only works with extensions disabled

Tags: windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

Internet Explorer was working fine on my Win 8.1, and then just stopped.

When I open IE11, it loads the window with the Favourites Bar, but does not load any pages. All options under the "Settings" gears are disabled. I can type in the address bar, but it won't load any pages. Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> does not trigger page load.

IE opens and is almost useless.

If I launch it with `iexplore -extoff`, everything works fine.

Using this I have disabled all add-ons but it still behaves exactly the same.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall the extensions just not disable them?

Comment: How do I uninstall?  The "remove" button is disabled in the manage add-ones window.

Comment: You will have remove them by hand

Comment: I have exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. One solution that seems to work for many users is to run **Internet Options** from Control Panel, and under **Advanced tab** select **Reset…**. However, all I got was a message letting me know that [resetting user customizations failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aT7FI.png).

The solution that worked for me was to run **Internet Explorer with no add-ons**, activate **Developer Tools by pressing F12** and then **closing the Developer Tools panel** and after that browser.

(I was also able to recreate the problem later by running Internet Explorer, opening Developer Tools and then killing the browser process.)

Comment: great! the f12 enchantment worked 4 me too !!! How did ya know it, man?